# How do I set the target Device Family for my Universal App Project

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

I made an Universal App but I only want to publish it for Desktops and not for Phones yet. I also have a Windows Phone 8 App of the same name that I want to keep for all windows phone 8.1 and windows phone 8 Users. How can I accomplish this? The store just doesn't seem to have any options to allow this.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 Mobile is still in preview. Only Desktop has RTMed. When Mobile is available there should be a checkbox on the dashboard. See Device families at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/mt148548.aspx#dist_vis

You can also limit the DeviceFamily in your manifest. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx

The Windows 10 app won't run on Windows Phone 8.1 so those users will get the 8.1 version even once the Windows 10 Mobile app is p published