# Can I submit Windows app only for windows 10 desktop?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

I'm developing an app which only for windows 10 desktop currently

(I didn't do too much with touch event, focus on mouse event now, and mobile platform should comes with other layout)

I'm wondering, can I submit an app to windows store and set the app only for desktop ?

it's built with universal project which support for all platforms, but best experience is for desktop platform for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `appxmanifest` file, the target device family can be set. It is `Windows.Universal` by default, but if we set it to a particular device family, the app will run only in that device family.

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

This answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727029/4575252

Comment: You need to open the manifest file with XML (Text) Editor to edit this value.